# R - I don't understand why my code generates a count rather than a sum

Tags: r, list, count, sum

I have a list of 10,000 values that look like this

```
      Points
1    118
2    564
3     15
4    729
5     49
6    614
```

Calling the list `t1` and running `sum(t1>quantile(t(t1),0.8))` I would expect to get a sum of the values in the list that are greater than the 80th quantile, but what I really get is a count (not a sum) of all the values.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Sorry, the language is R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum(t1[t1>quantile(t(t1),0.8), ])
```

To see the difference check `t1>quantile(t(t1),0.8)` and then `t1[t1>quantile(t(t1),0.8), ]`.

One is a logical vector and contains `TRUE` (resp. 1) if the value is greater than the 80% quantile and zero otherwise. 
The other is `t1` evaluate at that logical vector, so only values which are greater than the 80% quantile are returned

Answer (score 1):

`t1>quantile(t(t1),0.8)` is a boolean, i.e. a sequence of TRUE/FALSE values (you can check it easily). Consequently, the `sum` of this vector is the number of occurrences of `TRUE` values, i.e. the count of individuals that satisfy the condition you specify.

Comment: Thanks, but what would be a solution?

Comment: A solution would be : `sum(t1[t1>quantile(t(t1),0.8)])`. By doing this, you first filter `t1` to keep only those individuals that are greater than a given threshold, and in a second step you compute the sum of their values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Point = rnorm(10000))
sum(df$Point > quantile(df$Point, 0.8))
```

The second line returns the sum for a boolean vector (`TRUE/FALSE`), hence you get the count (the number of times `TRUE` occurs). Use

```
sum(df$Point[df$Point > quantile(df$Point, 0.8)])
```

to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ifelse fonction, that will add t1 if t1 is above your threshold and 0 otherwise

```
sum(ifelse(t1>quantile(t(t1),0.8),t1,0))
```